# Objective-C Multiple Cast

Tags: objective-c, class, casting, compiler-errors, protocols

Is it possible to cast an object in Objective-C so as to tell the compiler that its type could be one of many?

For example, in my [answer to iOS: Two Gestures, One Target-Action](https://stackoverflow.com/a/19626342/242933), I know an object will either be a `UITapGestureRecognizer` or a `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` but am not sure which one. And, both of those classes respond to `numberOfTapsRequired` but not through a common protocol. They just both implement the same property.

So, to get around compiler errors, I just cast the object as `UILongPressGestureRecognizer`. This works now, but if a future version of the iOS SDK changes the name of the `UITapGestureRecognizer` `numberOfTapsRequired` property (and left that of `UILongPressGestureRecognizer` unchanged), then my code would compile but crash with an unrecognized selector exception on a double-tap.

So, if there were a way I could tell the compiler, "Hey, I know this object is either one of two types," then that would allow me to make an accurate cast.

If you can't do this in Objective-C, do any programming languages allow this? I hear C# pretty much lets you do anything.

Comment: Keep things simple and just use two Target-Actions

Answer (score 0):

I don't think that a "multiple cast" exists in Objective-C, but you could use something like this to catch this issue at compile-time.

```
if([gestureRecognizer isKindofClass: [UITapGestureRecognizer class]]) {

     (UITapGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired;
}

else if([gestureRecognizer isKindofClass: [UILongPressGestureRecognizer class]]) {

     (UILongPressGestureRecognizer*)gestureRecognizer.numberOfTapsRequired;
}
```